# Identify the sequence

Tags: number-sequence

(Might be a spoiler)

> I was working on a famous problem, and I came up with a variation that can produce a sequence much harder to recognise than the original sequence.

Identify the problem which generates this sequence:

> ***1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 12, 15, 17, 21, 27, 32, 38, 48, 59, 70, 86, 107, 129, 156, 193...***

Hint:-

> Fibonacci

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**) Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> a[i] = a[i-3]+a[i-4]

Because

> Every number is the sum of its third and fourth predecessor.

Comment: You just beat me to it. It's not too hard to figure out if you start at the end of the provided sequence of numbers.

Comment: This does not work for the first 2...

Comment: That was not what I expected. This kind of took away the "fun" of the question. Good observation though. I would accept a situational definition, and not a mathematical one, like how Fibonacci originally did with rabbit pairs.

Comment: Also, the solution should explain the first 5 terms (My solution requires a single parameter)